# Log In/Log On Dialog in Catel

Tags: catel

How would you create a Login/Logon Dialog in Catel?

We currently make use of a Custom Splash screen with a Boot Class and a single BootTask to sleep until a successful login occurs or is cancelled.

Are there any other options?

**EDIT**

Here is some code of what we currently do:

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
      base.OnStartup(e);

      new Boot().RunWithSplashScreen<LoginViewModel>();
}
```

**Boot Class:**

```
public class Boot : BootstrapperBase<MainMenuWindow>
    {
        private Session CurrentSession = Session.Instance;

        protected override void InitializeBootTasks(IList<ITask> bootTasks)
        {
            bootTasks.Add(new ActionTask("Awaiting Login", delegate
                {
                    while (/*not successfully logged in*/) Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    if (/*login cancelled*/)
                        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(
                            delegate
                            {
                                App.Current.Shutdown();
                            }));
                }));

            base.InitializeBootTasks(bootTasks);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are also using prism, right? What I normally do is run the application normally (show the main window) and then show a login on top of that. If login fails => exit app. Another good idea is to look at the examples in Orchestra (github.com/orcomp/orchestra) which shows splash screens and main windows used together. Especially check out the Fluent ribbon example.

Comment: thanks. I did try the 'show main menu first and then show login screen' method but ran into some issues, which got me using the splash screen service. cannot remember what issues I had, was a while ago but I'll have a look at the options you've presented here.